Filtering column for two values
I want to filter a sheet by Completion Date and blanks, as well as filtering by Status. The statuses I want are In Queue and Completed. This should result in a sheet that shows what was completed on the date Input, what's In Queue, as well as blanks which will let me know that a batch was not completed today.
I made a macro that sends the active sheet as an email to the team.
Code for the working email portion as well as for the filters. I tried autofilter but it filters by check in date not completion date, and it tries to find "In Queue" inside the check in date column.
The name of the first sheet is MasterLog.
Sub filter_multiple()

With Sheets("MasterLog").Range("C3")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("C1").Value
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("I1").Value
End With

With Sheets("MasterLog").Range("E3")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("P1").Value
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("Q1").Value
End With

End Sub


Sub EmailActiveSheet()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileFullPath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    
    ' Set the worksheet you want to send
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterLog") 'Replace "SheetName" with your sheet's name
    
    ' Create a temporary copy of the sheet as a new workbook
    ws.Copy
    Set TempWB = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Define the temporary directory
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    
    ' Check if the temporary directory exists, and create it if not
    If Len(Dir(TempFilePath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir TempFilePath
    End If
    
    TempFileName = "TempSheet"
    FileFullPath = TempFilePath & TempFileName & ".xlsx"
    
    ' Save the temporary workbook
    TempWB.SaveAs FileFullPath, FileFormat:=51 ' 51 represents the xlsx file format
    TempWB.Close False
    
    ' Create a new Outlook instance
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) ' 0 represents a mail item
    
    ' Compose the email
    With OutMail
        .To = "adaviscayron@nhanced-semi.com" ' Replace with the recipient's email address
        .Subject = "Email Macro Test" ' Replace with your email subject
        .Body = "Hello, please find the attached sheet." ' Replace with your email body
        
        ' Attach the specific sheet
        .Attachments.Add FileFullPath
        
        ' Uncomment the next line to display the email before sending (for testing)
         .Display
        
        ' Uncomment the next line to send the email immediately
        ' .Send
    End With
    
    ' Clean up
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    ' Delete the temporary file
    Kill FileFullPath
    
End Sub


Have you tried recording a macro while filtering the data?  That's typically a good starting point.

I believe for a multi-criteria filter you'd have a Operator:=xlOr or xlAnd instead of the same line a second time. Is your code not applying both filters and that's the issue? I'm not opening a file, post anything you need your file for as a markdown table or image, opening files creates security concerns.

This works for me:
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterLog")
    
    With ws.Range("A2:N" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                    Criteria1:=Array("=", ws.Range("C1").Value), _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, _
                    Criteria1:=Array(ws.Range("P1").Value, ws.Range("Q1").Value), _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub

